# Error: chol: input matrix must be positive definite

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, pattern-matching, octave, naivebayes

How can I fix this error?

**mvnpdf.m**

```
% y = mvnpdf(x,mu,Sigma)
% Compute multivariate normal pdf for x given mean mu and covariance matrix 
% sigma.  The dimension of x is d x p, mu is 1 x p and sigma is p x p.

function pdf = mvnpdf(x,mu,sigma)
  [d,p] = size(x);
  % mu can be a scalar, a 1xp vector or a nxp matrix
  if nargin == 1, mu = 0; end
  if all(size(mu) == [1,p]), mu = repmat(mu,[d,1]); end
  if nargin < 3
    pdf = (2*pi)^(-p/2) * exp(-sumsq(x-mu,2)/2);
  else
    r = chol(sigma);
    pdf = (2*pi)^(-p/2) * exp(-sumsq((x-mu)/r,2)/2) / prod(diag(r));
  end
```

**pdfdep.m**

```
function pdfmx = pdfdep(train, test)
% computes probability density for all classes
% assuming feature independence
% train - train set; the first column contains label
%   used to  compute mean and variation for all classes
% test - test set (without labels)
% pdfmx - matrix of probability density for all classes
%   class with label idx is stored in pdfmx(:,idx)

    classnb = rows(unique(train(:,1)));

    pdfmx = ones(rows(test), classnb);

    for cl=1:classnb
        clidx = train(:,1) == cl;

        mu = mean(train(clidx,2:end)); 
        sigma = cov(train(clidx,2:end));

        pdfmx(:,cl) = mvnpdf(test, mu, sigma);
    end
```

**mat.txt**

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
2   3   4   5   6   7   8   1 
3   4   5   6   7   8   1   2 
4   5   6   7   8   1   2   3
1   8   7   6   5   4   3   2
2   7   6   5   4   3   2   9
3   6   5   4   3   2   9   8 
4   5   4   3   2   9   8   7
1   8   7   6   5   4   3   2
3   6   5   4   3   2   9   8
```

**Error message:**

```
>> mat2 = mat;
>> pdfdep(mat, mat2)
error: chol: input matrix must be positive definite
error: called from
    mvnpdf at line 13 column 7
    pdfdep at line 20 column 15
>>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite self explanatory

> input matrix must be positive definite

Means that your matrix (`sigma`) is not positive definite, thus you cannot run cholesky decomposition on it. There are many ways used to estimate covariance in a nice manner, simply computing the empirical estimate (what you do by calling `cov`) does not work when your data is degenerated (it lies in low dimensional manifold). One of the simplest solutions is to use "pulled estimator" of form:

```
cov(X) + eps * I
```

instead of

```
cov(X)
```

thus just change

```
sigma = cov(train(clidx,2:end));
```

to incorporate this additional `+ eps * I` (where `I` is identity matrix of appropriate dimension).

Comment: Yes it does, with big enough epsilon it will solve the issue.